Running an Agent Job using Azure Shared Access Key Credential
I'd like to have a SQL agent job that copies a file up to Azure Storage using a Shared Access Key Credential.
The credential is set up and works for backup and restore process, but I'd like to use it for copying files up to blob storage. I don't mind using PowerShell, CMD or SISS, I just want to be able to leverage the credential
Any Ideas?
Cheers
Alex
